# Not able to pass the data from the body in post request express js with swagger

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

In the Swagger, Not able to pass data from the request body with the post request. I'm able to send the value from a parameter.

**Swagger:** [image]

**Swagger UI** [image]

**Error**

```
 Error: Cannot find module '../encodings.js'
Require stack:
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\body-parser\index.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\express\index.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\app.js
- d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\bin\www
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at Module.require (d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\safeloaderjs\core\Safeloader.js:20:41)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.getCodec (d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:65:27)
    at Object.getDecoder (d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
    at getDecoder (d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:45:18)
    at readStream (d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:180:15)
    at getRawBody (d:\YoJo-Project\sso-login-yojo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
```

Comment: Have a look at the error stack: Error: `Cannot find module '../encodings.js'`. Where do you use the module `encoding.js`? Check your `import` and `require('<module_path>`.

Comment: actually I'm not using the encoding.js. I using a simple post request whenever i try to send the post request with data from body i'm getting this error.

Comment: my code is very simple, just I'm passing a data from body in post request with help of swagger ui in express js. it expecting the encoding.js from express lib.